# Switch to secondary oracle database when primary is down in java simple JDBC

Tags: java, sql, oracle, servlets, jdbc

I am trying out sample application to demonstrate Oracle Data Guard , I have written a simple Java Servlet to fetch the data from an oracle DB .

Servlet Looks Something Like This:

```
package com;

import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class DisplayServlet extends HttpServlet {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();



        try{
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.10.220.4:1529:poc","poc","poc");

            PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("select * from admin_emp");
            //ps.setInt(1,roll);

            out.print("<table width=50% border=1>");
            out.print("<caption>Result:</caption>");
            ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();

            /* Printing column names */
            ResultSetMetaData rsmd=rs.getMetaData();
            int total=rsmd.getColumnCount();
            out.print("<tr>");
            for(int i=1;i<=total;i++)
            {
                out.print("<th>"+rsmd.getColumnName(i)+"</th>");

            }
            out.print("</tr>");

            /* Printing result */
            while(rs.next())
            {
                out.print("<tr><td>"+rs.getInt(1)+"</td><td>"+rs.getString(2)+"</td><td>"+rs.getString(3)+"</td><td>"+rs.getString(4)+"</td></tr>");

            }
            out.print("</table>");

        }catch (Exception e2) {e2.printStackTrace();}

        finally{out.close();}
    }

}
```

So My question when this database fails i should be automatically connecting to other database in another host , Before it throws a time out exception .

Answer (score 0):

This is usually handled through tnsnames.ora file. So there is not need to write any code. Even thin JDBC drivers support tnsnames lookups.

- Set JVM property to point onto tnsnames.ora file
- Ask DBAs to provide you connect string for Data Guard
- In you code while creating DB connection use name of tnsnames entry instead of host:port:sid

The other option is to hardcode Oracle `connect string` directly into your code.

Answer (score -1):

Before Timeout Exception?

Calculate the time in a seperate thread and on the given time change the connection variable to the 2. server.